# Twilio: Finding the SID of a call or a conference

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am having trouble find the SID of a call or a conference once it is created.

I need these parameters, in order to modify a live call, or kick a participant from the conference.

***Starting with a basic example (I'm coding in Ruby) :***

//Paramaters\

> `require 'twilio-ruby'`
>
> `account_sid = '//myaccount#'`
>
> `auth_token = '//myauthtoken'`

Creating the call :

> `@client = Twilio::REST::CLient.new account_sid, auth_token`
>
> `call = @client.account.calls.create({:from => '//outgoing#', :to => '//incoming#', :method => 'get'})`
>
> `puts call.sid`

Then the hangup part :

> `@hangup = @client.account.calls.get("CallSid")`
>
> `@call.update(:status => 'completed')`
>
> `puts @call.direction`

So as you can see, to execute the second part (hangup), I need to have the Sid of the call that was just created in order to modify it later *(either redirect it, put it in a conference, or hang it up.)*

Comment: What's the problem? is `puts call.sid` not outputting the SID correctly?

Comment: Okay, after retesting, the sid does get output in my console: 'CA99e3ecf37eabfb520fa34fca4d28c623' is what i got testing it on my root window on my server.

Comment: My followup question is once that has been outputed in the Terminal window, in the `@hangup = @client.account.calls.get("CallSid")` line, if I put call.sid in the `calls.get(call.sid)` part, would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puts call.sid` should be outputting the SID to the console.

If you need to use it later, you can assign it to a variable instead:

```
@sid = call.sid

@hangup = @client.account.calls.get(@sid)
```

Comment: +1 (if I could no rep yet :/ I'll come back for it when I can ) That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a bunch Dylan!.

Comment: You can accept answers that work for you, even as a new user; just click the checkmark box under the voting arrows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll still be back to give you your deserved rep :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the non-ruby peeps that fall into this later:

You want the REST (not TwiML) docs.

Specifically for Conference http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference

And also Participants: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/participant

And you might as well check out Modifying Live Calls while your at it: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state